# How to filter suggest query by type

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Let's assume I have mapped multiple types like `Company` and `Customer`. These types are mapped with suggest fields. Everything works when I execute a `suggest` query for both types. Now I want to limit the query to find result for one type. I read [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/suggester-context.html) about the Context Suggester. This is also working but now I cannot find both types, because I have to set the context. Leaving the context empty returns no results. How to cut the Gordian knot? Is there a different way than using the `Context Suggester`?

Here is my (little shortened) mapping for `Company`:

```
 "company": {
    "dynamic": "false",
    "_id": {
       "path": "Id"
    },
    "properties": {
       "name": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "payloads": true,
          "preserve_separators": true,
          "preserve_position_increments": true,
          "max_input_length": 50,
          "context": {
             "type": {
                "type": "category",
                "path": "type",
                "default": [
                   "company"
                ]
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to achieve it with context suggester . I set the `path` in context to `_type`.

Example:

1) Mapping

```
put test/company/_mapping
{
 "company": {

    "properties": {
       "name": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "payloads": true,
          "preserve_separators": true,
          "preserve_position_increments": true,
          "max_input_length": 50,
          "context": {
             "type": {
                "type": "category",
                "path": "_type"
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
}

put test/customer/_mapping
{
 "customer": {

    "properties": {
       "name": {
          "type": "string"
       },
       "suggest": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "simple",
          "payloads": true,
          "preserve_separators": true,
          "preserve_position_increments": true,
          "max_input_length": 50,
          "context": {
             "type": {
                "type": "category",
                "path": "_type"
             }
          }
       }
    }
 }
}
```

2) Example Documents

```
  PUT test/company/1
    {
        "name": "hello company",
        "suggest": {
            "input": ["hello", "hello company"]
        }
    }

    PUT test/customer/1
    {
        "name": "hello customer",
        "suggest": {
            "input": ["hello again", "hello customer"]
        }
    }
```

3) Suggest: type company

```
POST test/_suggest
{
        "suggest" : {
            "text" : "hel",
            "completion" : {
            "field" : "suggest",
            "size": 10,
            "context": {
                "type": ["customer"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

4) Suggest : type customer

```
post test/_suggest
{
        "suggest" : {
            "text" : "hel",
            "completion" : {
            "field" : "suggest",
            "size": 10,
            "context": {
                "type": ["company"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

5) Suggest: type company & customer

```
post test/_suggest
{
        "suggest" : {
            "text" : "hel",
            "completion" : {
            "field" : "suggest",
            "size": 10,
            "context": {
                "type": ["company","customer"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Actually I tried it in a similar way, using `Nest` (a C# - client) without success. I think there was a little mistake, I will try it again. Thanks a lot for your time!